# JavaFX native bundle exe is throwing "JavaFx launcher Exception" where as Executable Jar file is perfectly running

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx-2, obfuscation, executable-jar

For long time I was facing an issue while running the application jar -

I am obfuscating the JAR using `Proguard` and that JAR file also contains some resource files like images, .version file, etc along with **publicCerts.store** file.

So to include resource file into final JAR I had specified all the resource files as

```
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*.jar,*.version,publicCerts.store
```

but while running my application JAR I was getting execption -

```
 Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.a(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
    pl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:
    47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitiali
    zed keystore
    at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseNotary.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
    at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseNotary.verify(Unknown Source)
    at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)
    at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29
    )
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore
    at java.security.KeyStore.isKeyEntry(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

I thought the obfuscation corrupting the publicCerts.store so use another obfuscation option for publicCerts.store

```
-adaptresourcefilenames publicCerts.store
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*.jar,.version
```

and it works. When I used to double click on by application jar it is showing my application window but now the native bundle executable (exe) is showing me this dialog in the same case at the same condition.

[image]

**Edited -**

```
I have debugged the issue and found that it's throwing exception - 
    java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available
```

I wonder the native bundle executable (exe) is made up from the same executable but the exe is not working. Here is ANT step to deploy the application and create the native bundle exe.

```
<target name="CreatingExe" depends="SignedJar">
            <fx:deploy width="800" height="600" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${dist}" outfile="${app.name}">
                <fx:info title="${app.title}"/>
                    <fx:application name="${app.title}" mainClass="${main.class}"/>
                    <fx:resources>
                        <fx:fileset dir="${distBI}" includes="*.jar"/>
                <fx:fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/temp"/>
            </fx:resources>
         </fx:deploy>
    </target>
```

FYI : I am running my build on Windows 8 O.S., 64 bit machine. I am deploying my JavaFX application in following steps-

```
Compiling JavaFX Code.
Creating JAR.
Obfuscating code.
Signing Jar
Creating Executable. 
Signing Executable. 

Build was successful.
```

**How to exclude publicCerts.store from obfuscation? Why the final exe is not working even the application jar is working?** Do I need to specify any thing else in fx:deploy task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a JavaFx native bundle the `ext` folder under `<JDK.HOME>` doesn't get included. What this folder contain is mostly the security stuff.

```
<!--Copy the ext library to the runtime lib-->
<copydir src="${java.home}/lib/ext"
    dest="${dist.jar.dir}/bundles/{YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME}/runtime/jre/lib/ext"
    includes="**/*"
/>
```